# SQL oracle: Need to display a query.

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

so i have 3 tables linked together named office, employee, and dependent.

office: Oid (PK), officeName

employee: EID(PK), Fname, Lname, JobTitle, Salary, DOH, Gender, DOB, OID(FK1),        Supervisor(FK2)

Dependent: DID(PK), Fname, Lname, Gender, EID(FK1)

Here is the link to the picture of the tables:
http://classweb2.mccombs.utexas.edu/mis325/class/hw/hw12a.jpg

I need to display concatenated name and EID of 5 employees with the largest number of dependents, if there is a tie for the five largest, then I need to display all of the tying employees.

I am confused on how to begin. please help :)
thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps start here - [select](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break down the problem:

How many dependents an EID has:

```
SELECT EID, COUNT(*) AS C
FROM Dependent
GROUP BY EID
```

Add a rank

```
SELECT EID, C, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT EID, COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM Dependent
  GROUP BY EID
) S
```

We want the first 5

```
SELECT EID 
FROM (
  SELECT EID, C, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS R
  FROM (
    SELECT EID, COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM Dependent
    GROUP BY EID
  ) S
) S2
WHERE R <= 5
```

Now ask for what you want:

```
SELECT * -- or whatever
FROM Employee 
WHERE EID IN (
  SELECT EID 
  FROM (
    SELECT EID, C, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS R
    FROM (
      SELECT EID, COUNT(*) AS C
      FROM Dependent
      GROUP BY EID
    ) S
  ) S2
  WHERE R <=5
) S3
```

I suggest you run each step and make sure it gives you the expected results.

Answer (score -1):

Ummm I would try something like this:

```
Select TOP 5
a.FNAME,
a.LNAME,
a.EID,
Count(b.EID) as Dependents
FROM employee a
LEFT JOIN dependent b on a.EID = b.EID
group by 1,2,3 order by Dependents desc
```

Comment: This will only give 5 results if there is a tie.

Comment: Actually, this will return a syntax error ("ORA-00923:  FROM keyword not found where expected").  And then when you fix that one, it will return another syntax error.